HP Z2 G9 workstation: Cannot boot Ubuntu, nor enter the BIOS
I have a HP Z2 G9 workstation with Ubuntu preinstalled.
Due to an update process went wrong, I accidentally deleted some important packages of my Ubuntu system (unfortunately I cannot remember the names, except for Mutter). When I did the screen went immediately black. Those packages were all the Unofficial software packages not provided by Ubuntu on my system.
Now, when I try to switch on the machine the following happen:

blanck screen
splash screen with (from top to bottom): Hp logo, this phrase "protected by HP Wolf security", a loading sign and  the Ubuntu logo.
The screen goes blanck forever

My aim is to restore enough Ubuntu packages to be able to interact again with the sytem. I tried to enter the BIOS to either use GRUB command line or to change the boot order to an external USB key. Unfortunately I am unable to do that.
Things I tried to get into BIOS:

press repeadetly ESC/F2/F10/F12 after switching the workstation ON (with and without the Fn key of the keyboard)
long press ESC/F2/F10/F12
pressing all F button alternatively
Nothings seemed to have any effect at all.

Weird facts to notice:

after a certain amount of time, pressing ESC makes the workstation beep. If I long press it beeps with a frequency of 1 per second, otherwise when I press ESC two times.
repeteadly pressing F10 results, after a while, in a single beep (after which nothing happens anymore)

My Workstation came with Ubuntu preinstalled. Might it be that I deleted some packages installed by HP that were essential to boot the machine? Is HP wolf security involved?
Specs of the machine: HP Z2 G9 i9-13900K/2x32GB/1TB SSD/8TB HDD T400 Linux Ubuntu
Please, any help is very well appreciated, I do not know what to try anymore...
P.S I read on another post that a problem might be that the Nvidia graphic card is preventing the display of the BIOS. Problem is that I only have two display ports (tried with both) and I do not know how to connect the monitor to the motherboard directly...

Without knowing which packages you removed, I don't know how much we can help beyond general recovery steps. Have you looked into Ubuntu boot repair? If your mainboard has a video connector, that's how you'd connect the monitor directly. But, why are you focusing on the BIOS if you do see the Ubuntu logo? That means you're already past the BIOS and that part is working OK.

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Thanks for the answer @music2myear!
My aim is to restore the lost packages of the ubuntu installation but after the ubuntu logo screen there is nothing I can do to interact with the system.
That is why I was focusing on the BIOS: I was hoping to reinstall them through Grub command line or by using an usb key with Ubuntu on it. Then again, I am not an expert so maybe there is a better way to deal with the problem?
For the mainboard, it is possible it doesn't have a video connector? on the back of my Workstation I can only see two display video port and nothing else...

Have you tried booting into single user mode from grub and reinstalling the packages that way? Sometimes, you have to press the DEL key to get into the BIOS.

Thank you all, I managed to solve the issue!
For future reference, here are the steps towards the solution:

I realised the machine was going into the BIOS, but nothing was visualised on the screen. I did it by looking at the layout of the BIOS interface on the web, and then blindly trying to boot Ubuntu from a USB key.
I suspected the problem was that the graphic signal was not being sent to the DPI ports of the motherboard
I connected the screen directly to the NVIDIA Graphic card (I had to find an adaptor since it only had micro-DPI ports that I did not notice before)
I booted into Ubuntu, from where I noticed the graphical interface was missing. I used the terminal instead.
I looked for the packages I had uninstalled on /var/log/dpkg.log
I reinstalled everything
The problem was (probably) that I uninstalled some HP drivers (oem-stella-meta, oem-stella-aron-meta oem-stella-factory-meta) that had ubuntu-desktop between its dependencies. This resulted in it being uninstalled.


Good fix! It's been a while since I last had to do it, but navigating a UI blind can be a real challenge, and when you succeed, it's a pretty good feeling. Just a tip: In the future, rather than trying to find an adapter, you could probably have removed the graphics card from the computer and this would have forced the BIOS to display through the onboard DP ports.

@music2myear Thanks for the tip!
